# What is the maximum delay for setInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm having problems on Firefox 15 and Chrome 21 with the following code:

```
setInterval(function () { console.log('test') }, 300000000000)
```

On both browsers, the function is run right away repeats very quickly.  Sure, that's a big number (representing about 10 years from now), but I wouldn't expect it to be treated as a tiny or negative number.  I haven't seen a maximum allowed delay in any documentation.  Does anyone know if there's a standard max, or if this is just the browsers being funny?

Comment: I suspect that the number may be coerced to a 32-bit integer somewhere along the way ...

Comment: @Pointy, that's probably a good guess.  Hmm... :-/

Comment: @Pointy.  It looks like 2^31-1 is safe, but 2^31 breaks, so you're almost definitely right.  If you post this as an answer, I'll give you the karma.

Comment: Is that the case regardless of which machine the code is being run on?

Comment: @Gareth.  Good question.  I've only tested on a couple computers.

Comment: "What's the maximum delay for `setInterval`?", 2**32ms ~ 50 days.

Comment: It's uses a signed integer, so the maximum delay is half of that, 24.855 days.
When delay is larger than 2147483647 or less than 1, the delay will be set to 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't find any documentation at the moment, but I wouldn't be surprised if the timer value had to fit in a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: This is correct. setInterval() fails with values larger than 32-bit signed int.

Comment: 2147483647 ms https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#return_value

Comment: @sudazzle which is the largest positive value you can fit in a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: @Pointy. A 32-bit signed integer value range [-2147483648 to 2147483647]

Answer (score 32):

The interval is stored in a signed 32-bit int (in the tested implementation: V8 in Google Chrome), so the behavior you're seeing is the result of the interval overflowing to a negative number (in which case it behaves as if the interval was `0`).  Thus, the maximum interval that you can use is `2**31 - 1`.

Here's how I determined that this was the case:

```
setInterval(function(){console.log("hi");}, Math.pow(2,31));
```

Behaves like the interval is `0`.

```
setInterval(function(){console.log("hi");}, Math.pow(2,31) - 1);
```

Doesn't fire in the time I was willing to wait.

```
setInterval(function(){console.log("hi");}, Math.pow(2,33) + 1000);
```

Behaves like the interval is `1000` (one second).  Here, the `2**33` doesn't affect the first 32 bits, so we get just `1000`.

The highest possible interval, `2**31-1ms` is a little shy of 25 days, so more than enough for anything reasonable.

Comment: The interval *in that particular implementation* is stored in .. but +1 for showing the methodology used.

Comment: Nice example tests.  I basically did the same thin in my comment on the question itself, but +1 for showing your work. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think that the maximum delay is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 which is 2,147,483,647ms. The maximum value of a signed 32 bit integer in ms. If it would be unsigned it would be 2<sup>32</sup>-1 = 4,294,967,295.

Comment: 2 Billions 147 Millions.

Answer (score 2):

Max is `2,147,483,647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1)

Be careful that if you make the number bigger than that, it will run immediately (Imaging that you put a negative value, so the browser will run infinitely loop)

```
setInterval(()=>console.log('n'),2147483647)
31
setInterval(()=>console.log('y'),2147483648)
38
(1588) y
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need an interval larger than `2,147,483,647` here's an example in TypeScript that will allow you to set an interval for a max of `458,496,310,632,933,156,516.92` days:

*Obviously, I have not tested that this works for that long :D.*

```
export const setLongInterval = (callback: any, timeout: number, ...args: any): Timeout => {
    let count = 0;
    const MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED = 2147483647;
    const maxIterations = timeout / MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED;

    const onInterval = () => {
        ++count;
        if (count > maxIterations) {
            count = 0;
            callback(args);
        }
    };

    return setInterval(onInterval, Math.min(timeout, MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED));
};

export const setLongTimeout = (callback: any, timeout: number, ...args: any): Timeout => {
    let count = 0;
    let handle: Timeout;
    const MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED = 2147483647;
    const maxIterations = timeout / MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED;

    const onInterval = () => {
        ++count;
        if (count > maxIterations) {
            count = 0;
            clearInterval(handle);
            callback(args);
        }
    };

    handle = setInterval(onInterval, Math.min(timeout, MAX_32_BIT_SIGNED));
    return handle;
};
```

Comment: *I have been running a test program since you posted your answer, and the interval has finally just fired off. I can confirm that it works.* Kidding.

Answer (score 1):

The delay argument is converted to a signed 32-bit integer. This effectively limits delay to 2147483647 ms, since it's specified as a signed integer in the IDL.

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#return_value)