# java script setInterval setting the delay?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

We have a use case of running the java script thread once a month. But what we observe is if we provide 3.5 weeks of delay for the setinterval function it does not respect it and starts getting scheduling once a second. is it a bug? does it have any maxiumum limit for giving the delay?

Interestingly same works fine for setTimeOut. -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="clock" />
<script>
    var int=setInterval(function(){clock()},1000*60*60*24*7*3.5);
    function clock()
    {
        var d=new Date();
        var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
        document.getElementById("clock").value=t;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="int=window.clearInterval(int)">Stop</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can just say `clock` instead of `function(){clock()}`.

Comment: In javascript with setInterval may occur some bugs, so will be better if you use setTimeout

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum delay for setInterval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633405/what-is-the-maximum-delay-for-setinterval)

Answer (score 1):

```
1000*60*60*24*7*3.5 = 0x7e2bce00
```

Which is awfully close to 0x80000000, I wonder if 32 but signed arithmetic somewhere might be responsible.

I just checked the specification and the timeout for `setInterval` and `setTimeout` are both defined as `long` values which means signed 32 bit. It is unclear how a negativetimeout value would be treated.

From the [WhatWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html) spec :

> long setTimeout(Function handler, optional long timeout, any...
>   arguments);

From the [WebIDL](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#idl-long) standard :

> The long type is a signed integer type that has values in the range
>   [−2147483648, 2147483647].

To fix your problem I can make two suggestions:

Since `setTimeout` works, use it and retrigger at the end of the processing function

Alternatively `setInterval` of half the period you want and use a toggle to execute your code every other time.