# Is there a maximum delay limit for window.setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Today I encountered an interesting problem with window.setInterval. When used with a sufficiently large delay (in this case the number of milliseconds in 30 days) it executes every second instead of every 30 days. Tested in latest Chrome and Firefox.

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/uLx2ezyp/)

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = new Date().toString();
}, 5000);
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = new Date().toString();
}, 2592000000);
```

I couldn't find any authoritative documentation on the max value of a delay in setInterval, and the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) doesn't mention anything. Other sources online suggest that delay should be able to accommodate any signed 32-bit integer.

Does the delay parameter in window.setInterval have a maximum value and what is it?

Comment: A note: the standard *does not* restrict on type/ranges for the timeout argument https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#timers (correct me if I'm wrong though)

Comment: It does indeed seem to be at 2147483648 (the smallest positive integer that isn't a signed 32-bit integer) where it first occurs.

Comment: Explained in Aaron Dufour's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633405/what-is-the-maximum-delay-for-setinterval

Comment: Does not happen in Opera 12.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [`setTimeout` documentation on the public wiki MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Maximum_delay_value) there is indeed a maximum, though it doesn't seem "official" - the limitation is a signed 32 bit integer.

> ### Maximum delay value
>
> Browsers including Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox
>   store the delay as a 32-bit signed integer internally. This causes an
>   integer overflow when using delays larger than 2147483647, resulting
>   in the timeout being executed immediately.

The value of `2592000000` is indeed larger than `2147483647` thus causing the overflow.

Comment: "According to the setTimeout documentation" --- it's not a "setTimeout documentation" but a public wiki

Comment: @zerkms Since MDN is so much more readable than the official specification, it's generally considered a decent proxy. And the inclusion of implementation notes like this makes it more practical.

Comment: @zerkms that would make it merely "not official documentation". However, it's a documentation nonetheless, because (with a risk of reaching semantic satiation) the page _documents_ the behaviour of `setTimeout`. It doesn't matter who wrote it, it still _is_ a writeup about the function.

Comment: @Vld I partially agree with you. For me it looks slightly misleading though. (when one speaks about standards - they need to be 200% accurate in terms)

Comment: @zerkms fair enough - I've specified it's MDN.